# firefox blocks any resource that has the word "reset" on it

Tags: firefox, browser, troubleshooting

Firefox blocks pages with the word "reset" on the URL it blocks resource file "reset.css"

I did a clean reinstall of firefox 3,4 and 11.  I even uninstalled my antivirus applications.

This does not happen on my chrome browser or any other browser. Is there a way to debug this behavior just to point me to the right direction which is causing this to happen.

This post contains the word reset and cannot be loaded on firefox too. I am using chrome right now.

I also tried downloading portable firefox browser but It has the same problem.

Comment: Does it block all files containing the word reset or just all files that have "reset" in the filename/URL?

Comment: it blocks files that have reset in the URL. this is what I noticed. Maybe it blocks other words too. I checked on firebug that it aborts the download of the "reset.css" file.

Comment: Do you have any adblockers installed? And have you tried creating a different [Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Profiles) or starting Firefox into [safe mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode)?

Comment: creating a new profile and running on safemode didn't change anything :| i am totally confused about this.

Comment: FWIW, I have tried to reproduce this using PaleMoon 9.2 and Firefox 3.6.12, and couldn't with either.  I've looked on bugzilla, and all similar reports seem to be down to Firefox extensions or some other security software installed on the PC.  Check if you've got a proxy server configured, which might be running some form of web filtering software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this is a virus called "**pws panda 547**" only Dr. Web was able to detect it. A very weird Trojan that affects only Firefox.